# Why I can not run Docker container? you are not authorized to perform this operation: server returned 401

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Something is wrong with permissions(401).I have a simple Spring Boot app

```
drwxrwxr-x   7 miki miki  4096 Jan  7 07:06 ./
drwxr-xr-x 158 miki miki 12288 Jan  7 07:06 ../
-rw-rw-r--   1 miki miki   178 Jan  7 07:06 Dockerfile
drwxrwxr-x   8 miki miki  4096 Jan  6 15:57 .git/
-rw-rw-r--   1 miki miki   395 Jan  4 12:40 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--   1 miki miki    37 Jan  4 12:40 heroku.yml
drwxrwxr-x   3 miki miki  4096 Jan  4 12:40 .mvn/
-rwxrwxr-x   1 miki miki 10284 Jan  4 12:40 mvnw*
-rw-rw-r--   1 miki miki  6734 Jan  4 12:40 mvnw.cmd
-rw-rw-r--   1 miki miki  1238 Jan  4 12:40 pom.xml
-rw-rw-r--   1 miki miki  1169 Jan  4 12:40 README.md
drwxrwxr-x   5 miki miki  4096 Jan  4 13:19 src/
drwxrwxr-x   9 miki miki  4096 Jan  4 13:59 target/
```

I can build image with Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN addgroup -S miki && adduser -S miki -G miki
USER miki:miki
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

When I try to  run it

```
docker run -p 8090:8090 praksaaspring
docker: you are not authorized to perform this operation: server returned 401.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I can run Nginx

```
docker run --detach --name web1 nginx:latest
aa5c305fa12134b281b665a766f7e4579e3e52ee11db218ed960e92647dcc758
```

How it comes that my app fails?

How to solve this problem? I tried to add USER but I got the same.

Comment: It's hard to know what's going on without more context. Is port 8090 already in use on the machine?

Comment: @Brad NO,I checked with lsof :8090,shows nothing.